# JQuery Datepicker erases already filled date field

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, datepicker

could anyone please help?
I am using jquery datepicker for several fields and in an update form in php and it updates dates in database. All seems to work great except the fact that if some of the date fields are already populated in DB, the datepicker does not display them and upon update it erases the value in DB too.
the php sample:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
    } );
</script>
```

...

```
<td><input type="text" id="datepicker" name="IM_request" value="'.$row["IM_request"].'"/></td>
```

So the variable **$row["IM_request"]** does not display if datepicker is enabled. if i disable it, it works fine, but a lot of manual work.
Any idea how to make the datepicker-enabled input field to display the value from DB?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i can display the time if i set the variable to: `$oriIM_request=$row["IM_request"];`
and change the `$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");` 
to 
`$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("setDate", $oriTime);`
but then the time is in wrong format as soon as i change it. is it possible to combine those two?

Comment: how many input with id="datepicker" do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. Instead of:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "yy-mm-dd");
} );
```

I should have used:

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});
} );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" id="txtSelectedDate" value="20-01-01" />

$('#txtSelectedDate').datepicker({
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
});
```

JSFiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/LgTZt/211/

Comment: this did not help, but thank you i have finally figured it out.